# Can't get Unity/Samsung Adaptive Performance to run when not development build

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get Unity/Samsung Adaptive Performance working.

Everything is good in the editor and in fact it's working when I create a development build.

However as soon as I build with Development Build unchecked, I can't access Holder.Instance and none of the Default Scalers work.

Any help appreciated.